# Why Scala match is superior to if statements?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

In [Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/) article by Twitter, they say the following:

> Use returns to clarify and enhance readability, but not as you would
>   in an imperative language; avoid using them to return the results of a
>   computation. Instead of

```
def suffix(i: Int) = {
  if      (i == 1) return "st"
  else if (i == 2) return "nd"
  else if (i == 3) return "rd"
  else             return "th"
}
```

> prefer:

```
def suffix(i: Int) =
  if      (i == 1) "st"
  else if (i == 2) "nd"
  else if (i == 3) "rd"
  else             "th"
```

> but using a match expression is superior to either:

```
def suffix(i: Int) = i match {
  case 1 => "st"
  case 2 => "nd"
  case 3 => "rd"
  case _ => "th"
}
```

**In this specific example**, why is match expression superior compared to the if/else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general `match` is more readable and explains your intention more clearly. But in this exact example, it has an added benefit, that `match` will emit not a series of `if`s, but a `switch` bytecode instruction (the [`tableswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/Instructions2.doc14.html) one in this case), which is likely to improve performance a bit.

You can assert that in this case `switch` will be emitted with the [`@switch`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.switch) annotation:

```
def suffix(i: Int) = (i: @switch) match {
  case 1 => "st"
  case 2 => "nd"
  case 3 => "rd"
  case _ => "th"
}
```

Comment: `is likely to improve performance a bit.` Any rough estimate on what `a bit` means?

Comment: @KevinMeredith In bytecode it literally replaces 3 comparisons (+ variable loads onto stack) with a single tableswitch instruction. It should be quite minor for 3 comparisons, unless it's in some tight loop. But in the tight loop JIT kicks in, and then things may vary a lot. Also this "emit switch for match" behaviour is quite brittle: it works only for matches against literal constants and `final val` identifiers. Still, `match` is better from the readability and coding style points as well. Thus it falls into "avoid premature pessimization" case: it's always preferable to a sequence of `if`s

Answer (score 1):

Essential in pattern matching is data type extraction. For examples and discussion see for instance [Extractor Objects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) and [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 1: Extractors](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html).

In the examples above the data type proves trivial and the benefit may come chiefly from readability.